# Global Variable with a dynamic value set by variable_get() in multisite

Tags: multi-sites, configuration

My question is, if I have a multisite environment what is the expected behaviour of global variables set like:

```
define('GLOBAL_VARIABLE' , variable_get('myvar'));
```

**'myvar'** is set in a module configuration page, all the sites share the same module. 
Will each site use an independent value for **'GLOBAL_VARIABLE'**? Which is what I want, each site to have different values for these global variables.

I can't seem to find any documentation on how this would work, or any previous questions either. It's something that would significantly affect how my module is structured, as there's a rather large amount of customization settings.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running true [multisite](https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site), then your sites are sharing the same *code*, but not the same *database catalogs*.

If you are in a situation where you only have access to a single database catalog, then you can use [prefixes](https://drupal.org/node/2622) to keep all of your instances separate.

It is also possible to [share tables](https://drupal.org/node/22267) in the same database catalog between multiple sites.  This is primarily meant for the `{users}` table, and cousins.  Sharing anything else, is likely a recipe for disaster.

So, to answer your question, the `{variables}` tables in a true multisite instance will be distinct unless you went out of your way to share them.

If you are using the [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/Domain) module to share some content between sites, then everything is really in the same database, and you will have a single `{variables}` table.

Now, you have the sample code

```
define('GLOBAL_VARIABLE', variable_get('myvar'));
```

This is not really a good idea; just use `variable_get('myvar')` wherever you need it.  If you have a lot of settings, then I would consider wrapping everything up in a singleton with a getter function that uses [`drupal_static()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7).